# How to send Mail in HP UX shell script with HTML + attachment?

Tags: email, unix, attachment, hp-ux

I am using below command for HTML page -

```
mailx -m -r $from -s $subject  Content-type: text/html $to <$message
```

I want to send attachment with it.

Comment: mailx -m -r $from -s $subject  Content-type: text/html $to <$message